# C++: Storing/accessing large objects with pointers to avoid running out of memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, stack-overflow, osx-yosemite

I have a C++ application that needs to have several extremely large unordered_maps loaded into memory simultaneously, and as a result I run out of <s>stack space</s> **heap space** during runtime (after some of the large unordered_maps are already loaded):

```
granger(34190, 0x7fff73062300) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8949833580846596096) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
[1]    34488 abort      ./granger
```

It seems like a potential solution would be to keep some of these large data structures <s>in the heap</s> **stored as pointers**, allowing me to avoid running out of memory. **Is this logic correct?**

If yes, here's the next issue I encounter when I try to implement the change:

- When I declare the unordered_maps that I want to keep in the heap, I do so using a pointer (e.g.; `unordered_map< string,vector<string> > *allMeds = mapAllMeds(ALL_MEDS_FILE);`
- The `mapAllMeds` function creates the large unordered_map and I assume it returns it to the pointer named `*allMeds`. No issue yet
- When I try to access elements in `*allMeds` (or any of the other unordered_maps I defined as pointers), I get the error `no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'unordered_map<string, vector<string> > *`.

**EDIT:** Example code for 3rd bullet point: `vector<string> medsForPatient = allMeds[aPatient.getDeid()];` returns the error I described above.

Does this mean that I can't use the normal `[]` operator when I try to access key/value pairs in unordered maps that are defined by pointer? If not, what workaround can be used instead?

**EDIT 2: OK, so the comments inform me that I'm running out of heap space, not stack space, but this really doesn't solve my problem at all: What approach can I take to get all of the data structures into memory at the same time without running out of addressable memory space?**

**EDIT 3:** Here's the function that the application crashes on running:

```
unordered_map<string,string> makeMedSynonyms() {
    unordered_map<string,string> medSynonymsMap;
    string delimiters = "|";
    ifstream ifs(MED_SYNONYMS_FILE);
    string line;
    while(std::getline(ifs, line)) {
        vector<string> medSynVec;
        string::size_type lastPos = line.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);
        string::size_type pos = line.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
        while(string::npos != pos || string::npos != lastPos) {
            medSynVec.push_back(line.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
            lastPos = line.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);
            pos = line.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
        }
        medSynonymsMap[medSynVec[0]] = medSynVec[1];
    }
    return medSynonymsMap;
}
```

Comment: You are running out of heap memory, not stack memory.

Comment: You can't use [] because you're getting back a pointer to the unordered_map, not an object of type unordered_map. You need to dereference that pointer first: vector<string> &myVec = (*allMeds)[myString];

Comment: You do not show your code for bullet #3, so how are we supposed to know?  show ALL relevant code, please.

Comment: OK so I'm running out of heap space, not stack, but still, how do I approach the issue?

Comment: To @OldProgrammer : example code added in the question as an edit.

Comment: "OK, so the comments inform me that I'm running out of heap space, not stack space, but this really doesn't solve my problem at all"  so change the question title/details to reflect your current problem

Comment: Edited question as requested.

Comment: If your app is 32bit then obvious solution is to switch to 64bit

Comment: @JDRomano2 If your application is 64-bit, then you have one poorly designed application, or you have a bug that has corrupted the heap (and is not a memory exhaustion error).

Comment: @JDRomano2 size=8949833580846596096 do you know how much memory is that? That's 8139826 Terrabytes, there is something definately wrong with your program. Unless you work for NASA or NBA

Comment: @JDRomano2 I agree with Slava.  There is something wrong with your program that is more than likely *not* memory related, given that ridiculously high value for `size`.  Maybe your objects are become invalidated, and you still have pointers to them, thus the crazy values?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Right, that makes sense. It doesn't look like I have any dangling pointers or the like, so I'm combing through the function where the crash occurs to see where the problem is. I've added the function as an edit to the question.

Comment: Your example code shows no pointers.

Comment: @JDRomano2 - `medSynonymsMap[medSynVec[0]] = medSynVec[1];`  You ddid't check if there are at least 2 entries in `medSynVec`.  If the number of entries < 2, that line invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Wow, simply testing for `medSynVec.size() == 2` seems to have resolved the issue. I wonder why not doing so could have resulted in such bizarre behavior.

Comment: @JDRomano2 I posted my comment as an answer.  Anytime you go out of bounds of a vector, expect anything to happen, including what you observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue with the function is this:

```
  medSynonymsMap[medSynVec[0]] = medSynVec[1];
```

You didn't check to see if `medSynVec` has at least 2 entries.  If the number of entries is < 2, then the line above invokes undefined behavior.